# Magento Buy x get y free

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to create a shopping cart rule for buy x get y free.  Currently it is set to buy 3 get 1 free.  If a customer changes the quantity of the item in the cart to 4 the rule applies; however, if the same item is in the cart 4 times, it is not applying the discount.

Any way of getting this working?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you'd be better off finding a way to discover this, and converting it to a single item of multiple quantities, rather than multiple items of single quantities.. which is what it sounds like you're describing.

Comment: Yea, the thing is, the product is customizable.  (ie all 4 would have custom options that are different which is why it is 4 items with quantity 1)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: That works for me.